# Can't start a cmd.exe shell with ConEmu

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, conemu

I've installed ConEmu on a Windows 10 64bits machine. It worked fine for a few hours. But today, while trying to start a simple cmd.exe shell, I get two errors message.

1. in a dialog box, it says that

   > 16 bits application is not supported. Impossible to start or execute the program "\??\C:\Users[MyUserName]\cmd.exe" because it is incompatible with 64 bits version of Windows. Please contact the software editor to … bla bla bla.
2. In the ConEmu terminal, it displays the following :

   > Can't create process, ErrCode=0x000000D8,
   >
   > Description:
   >   Cette version de %1 n’est pas compatible avec la version de Windows
   >   actuellement exécutée. Vérifiez dans les informations système de votre
   >   ordinateur, puis contactez l’éditeur de logiciel.
   >
   > Current directory: C:\Users[MyUserName]
   >
   > Command to be executed:
   >   "C:\Users[MyUserName]\cmd.exe"  /k "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\CmdInit.cmd"
   >
   > Press Enter or Esc to close console, or wait...

What's Working:

- cmd.exe is OK if started standalone (aka [Win]+[R])
- Other shells, commands or apps inside ConEmu are doing just fine (PowerShell, PuTTy, CygWindows, notepad++,  etc.).
- I can also start cmd.exe just fine from other shells (Powershell and CygWindows) inside ConEmu.

I tried to remove it completely, cleaning the directory, including clink addon and xml settings files in `%APPDATA%`. Still the same issue.

I'm no Windows expert. Do you have any idea where that might come from ?

Comment: What is the hell cmd.exe in Users subfolder? Isn't it a virus? Cmd.exe is always located in system32!

Comment: That's the point. I don't see any cmd.exe inside the user subfolder. Is there the equivalent of the `which` command in windows ?

Comment: `where cmd` is the equivalent of `which cmd`

Comment: I just wipe clean my user directory and it works fine new. However, I can't explain it. Thanks for your help. What is the best way to close a topic / mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall ConEmu

1. Remove registry (download Microsoft Fix it utility and clean up registry)
2. Uninstall from control panel
3. Then Install

Comment: Thanks @ihemant360 but as I mentionned in the question, I already did it (although I forgot to say that I also cleaned the registry.